# Fetch data from more then 5 tables from UserID common in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

we are trying to build an application using PHP and MYSQL here we have more then 5 different category wise table like `tblcategory1`, `tblcategory2`, `tblcategory3` and so on.

And each of the category table have a common `userID` field in all the tables.

We want to check in all the tables what are the entries we have with that particular `userID`.

Is there any query to checking from multiple tables?

Thank you (in advance)

Comment: You can use `union`  in mysql

Comment: Consider re-design your db...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative structure to @LaurenceFrost answer is to use `UNION ALL` to bring the tables together, then filter that result.

```
SELECT
    columnName
FROM
(
    SELECT userID, columnName FROM tblcategory1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT userID, columnName FROM tblcategory2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT userID, columnName FROM tblcategory3
    UNION ALL
    SELECT userID, columnName FROM tblcategory4
    UNION ALL
    SELECT userID, columnName FROM tblcategory5
)
   ilvCategoryAll
WHERE
   userID = 1
```

This layout becomes much more friendly when you have JOINs and other business logic, which you don't really want to have to repeat for every source table.

Also, it should be noted that I used `UNION ALL` rather than `UNION`.  This is because `UNION` expressly removes duplicates, which can be an expensive process *(even if there are no duplicates to find)*.  `UNION ALL`, however, does not do this de-duplication and is significantly lower cost.

*Note: the `ilv` in `ilvCategoryAll` means "in-line-view".*

Comment: Yes this helped me! Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes you need to look at the UNION keyword. It roughly works like this:

```
SELECT  columnName
FROM    category1
WHERE   userID = 1

UNION

SELECT  columnName
FROM    category2
WHERE   userID = 1

UNION

SELECT  columnName
FROM    category2
WHERE   userID = 1
```

This is essentially 3 separate queries which all run as one, and the results are all joined together to form one list of results.

For more info: [UNION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)

Comment: This most likely should be `UNION ALL` unless there is an express requirement for the de-duplication provided by `UNION`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer it helped a lot!